# Jasper report PDF not taking chinese characters

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am unable to embed Chinese characters into pdf using jasper reports.
I am getting english characters but not the text in chinese characters.
Would appreciate of someone can provide me a quick fix for this issue.

Comment: You need to choose a font that is Chinese compatible. Have you added the font ??

Comment: Yes i used Tahoma and also tried arial unicode MS..nothing worked till now.

Answer (score 1):

Add DynamicJasper-core-fonts-1.0.jar as a resource to the report you are trying to use and check pdf Embeded in the field that has Chinese characters.

You can find and download it from http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/ar/com/fdvs/DynamicJasper-core-fonts/1.0/

Answer (score 0):

Inside your   tag add the following

```
<font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial Unicode MS" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
```

Also make sure that Arial font extension jar in class path. Search internet for arial font extension jar.